# Past value from child fragment -> mainactivity cannot cast fragment_fr_event_Birthday to fragment_fr_event_wedding android studio

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a Fragment inside the mainActivity, the fragment contains fragmentcontainerView which can be replaced by multiple child fragments with spinner onselectedListener. I want to able to pass those values from the child fragment via eg: Do something with: `fragmentevent.TogetFName();` with a button in Mainactivity. In the parent fragment , I get the value from the child fragment(fragment_Birthday) with `fragment_fr_event_birthday = (fragment_fr_event_Birthday) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_event_child_fragment);` and other value from other childfragment with   `frag_fr_event_wed = (fragment_fr_event_wedding) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_event_child_fragment);`, I know that they cannot be assigned with the different fragment class at once, but is there a clever way to do this or is there any other way I can pass value from child -> parent fragment->mainActivity
MainActivity:

```
 public void onClick(View view){
case "Event":
                Fragment_fr_Event fragment_fr_event = (Fragment_fr_Event) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_generated_mainView);
                        if(fragment_fr_event.TogetWedChildFcoupleName() !=null && fragment_fr_event.TogetEventType().equals("Wedding")){
                            testThis.setText(fragment_fr_event.TogetWedChildFcoupleName());
                        }if( fragment_fr_event.TogetEventType().equals("Birthday") && fragment_fr_event.TogetBirthdayFName() !=null){
                            testTat.setText(fragment_fr_event.TogetBirthdayFName());

            }
}
```

ChildFragment(BirthdayFragment):

```
 public String TogetEventBirthdayFName (){
        EditText FBirthdayName = rootView.findViewById(R.id.Edittext_birthDay_FirstName);
        return FBirthdayName.getText().toString();
    }
```

ChildFragment(Wedding fragment):

```
public String toGetFcoupleName(){
        EditText FCoupleName = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView_wedding_Name);
       return FCoupleName.getText().toString();
    }
```

ParentFragment(EventFragment):

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        Spinner TypeEventSpinner = rootview.findViewById(R.id.type_event);
        TypeEventSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String tag_items = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                switch (tag_items){
                    case "Wedding":
                        frag_fr_event_wed = new fragment_fr_event_wedding();
                        FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_event_child_fragment, frag_fr_event_wed).disallowAddToBackStack().commit();
                        break;
                    case "Birthday":
                        fragment_fr_event_birthday = new fragment_fr_event_Birthday();
                        transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_event_child_fragment , fragment_fr_event_birthday).disallowAddToBackStack().commit();
                        break;

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
    }
 public String TogetWedChildFcoupleName(){
        if(frag_fr_event_wed !=null){
             frag_fr_event_wed = (fragment_fr_event_wedding) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_event_child_fragment);
        return frag_fr_event_wed.toGetFcoupleName();
        }return "Empty";
    }

 public String TogetBirthdayFName(){
        if(fragment_fr_event_birthday != null){
         fragment_fr_event_birthday = (fragment_fr_event_Birthday) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_event_child_fragment);
            return fragment_fr_event_birthday.TogetEventBirthdayFName();
        }
        return "Empty";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest , I couldn't understand what  you did there , but i got what you want , you want to communicate with parent's parent class , the way you are doing it made it so complicated even it's not readable , **BUT** of course there are always a good way to do something , in your case there are `Android Navigation Component` , which give you the simplicity and power to do make it much more easy to handle , You can put all your fragment in one graph and from within the destinations "fragment are called destinations here" you can communicate with other fragment and the parent using actions and global actions "going from one fragment to another is called action here" parameters, but there are no need to a parent's parent here , all destinations and its parent can share one `ViewModel` which will allow you to share data all around your app .

You can read more if it sound good to you [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation)